# What is the smallest possible .blend file size in 2.8x?

Tags: blend-files, memory-management

I'm trying to make a container library .blend file for common node groups and I cannot get the file to be smaller than 51.3 KiB (52 506). Can you do better?

[image: screenshot of "empty" blend file structure]